# Emacs (Aquamacs) using wrong mode (sometimes)

Tags: emacs, mode, aquamacs

I'm using version 2.1 of Aquamacs and django-mode from https://github.com/myfreeweb/django-mode. I installed it (after installing yasnippets) by adding

```
(require 'django-html-mode)
(require 'django-mode)
(yas/load-directory "path-to/django-mode/snippets")
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.djhtml$" . django-html-mode))
```

to my .emacs file. But sometimes Aquamacs uses the standard HTML mode instead of django-html-mode. This happens whenever a file starts with an html tag.

What do I have to change to make Aquamacs prioritize the file's extension instead of it's content (at least for .djthml files - everything else works just fine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `magic-mode-alist` and `magic-fallback-mode-alist` (although the latter *shouldn't* be applied if the file extension is in `auto-mode-alist`).  You also need to watch out for case; Emacs is likely to consider `FOO.DJHTML` to *not* match `"\\.djhtml"`.  I don't have Aquamacs installed, but Emacs.app has HTML recognition regexps in `magic-fallback-mode-alist`.

BTW, if it *is* case sensitivity, change the `auto-mode-alist` line to

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.[Dd][Jj][Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]$" . django-html-mode))
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the way to do it, but I put `(setq magic-mode-alist nil)` into my .emacs file and now everything seems to work. Thank you very much.